# Downloading HTTPS resources of a webpage for Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing an extension for Google Chrome that converts a given page to PDF. To achieve this functionality, I download the HTML of the page and pass it to an NPAPI DLL, through JavaScript, where the conversion happens and the PDF file is created.

I've implemented this functionality for pages of type `http://*`, but it doesn't work for pages of type `https://*`. I need to download the HTTPS resources (CSS, images, etc.) of that webpage and modify the HTML before passing it to the NPAPI DLL.

I couldn't find any good links that explain how it could be done for Chrome. Please give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't quote the error message you receive but I guess that your extension is simply not allowed to access HTTPS. Please check your `manifest.json`, it should list both `"http://*/*"` and `"https://*/*"` under `"permissions"`.

Documentation: [permissions in the manifest](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions), [match patterns](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html).

Comment: We've written a similar extension for Firefox that uses Firefox-specific APIs to download the DOM, and the https images/css/etc. data separately. When I request a content: document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML using chrome.tabs.executeScript, I don't get the HTTPS resources embedded within the page. I've checked the manifest.json file and it does have permissions set (https://*/*) already. Essentially, I want my extension to work for, for example, Gmail webpage while I'm logged in, and convert it to a PDF file.

Comment: What do you mean, the source code you get doesn't match the web page? Btw, it should be `document.documentElement.outerHTML`.

Comment: Yes, the DOM, that my NPAPI DLL gets, is passed to another DLL that does the main job of converting the webpage. When I open one such document that has HTTPS resources embedded, I get an error from Acrobat saying "Acrobat does not allow connection to xyz.com." I'm  a little weak at Web Technologies, so unable to understand the problem in detail. I just know that we had to download the HTTPS resources separately for our Mozilla Firefox plugin and modify the HTML code before passing it to the DLL.
PS:Changed document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML by document.documentElement.outerHTML

Comment: Okay, I think I now understand the problem. So, I'm able to get the HTML of the page and pass it to the DLL for conversion. The problem happens when the HTML contains images, CSS, or other data, that have links/source of type https://*. When this HTML is passed to Acrobat, it is unable to download the images, CSS, etc. because it cannot access HTTPS links. So, we download the data at JS level, write them to a temp file, and append extra Adobe tags with the HTML that contain HTTPS link<->temp-file mapping where Acrobat downloads the data from.